# Wpf MainWindow encapsulating multiple Windows - make StartupUri show many windows

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, user-interface, window

The aim is to create an object that contains a number of WPF windows, which would represent a unit that should always be shown together, each `Window` retaining its own individual responsibilities - say choosing to be laid out on a screen X ...

Now because WPF is a single-window architecture, I would like to **wrap this list of Windows in a single `Window` object**, so that it could be set as StartupUri, for instance.

- I know I could manually `Show()` each `Window` in `Application` startup, but that is not the point - I need a collection of windows that stick together and which I can easily call upon anywhere in my codebase, knowing I have one class that has taken care of the linkage.
- Not interested in Multiple Document Interface MDI here

I do not know how to implement such an adapter, I tried to override `BeginInit`, but that did not get called at all.

#### How to stop Window initialization

```
public class MultiWindow : Window
{
    private readonly IList<Window> _windows = new List<Window>();

    public void Register(Window window)
    {
        _windows.Add(window);
    }

    public override void BeginInit()
    {
        foreach (var w in _windows)
            w.Show();
        // base.BeginInit();
    }
}
```

*I do not understand `Window` lifecycle much, is there anyhow I could cancel the initialization and show the list of registered windows instead?*

Comment: Where are these Windows created?  How do you plan to deal with the Close() event on a Window if you need a set to remain together.  What is the functional requirement?

Comment: @BalamBalam The windows are registered throughout the application lifecycle, and in the specific scenario that im thinking about, they are created wheneever a new display is attached to the computer (and actually unregistered when secondary screens are removed). also, say there is dual monitors (so two windows), then at certain times the windows may be hidden and then need to be shown again together. so the code here is not completely fitting, but for illustration of the problem. i have not thought through the disposal yet because im not sure how to group-spawn dynamically like that.

Comment: OK but what is "the application" in "registered throughout the application lifecycle"?  Where are these Windows created.  And we are talking about a WPF Window?   What about a Page or Dialog Box?

Comment: @BalamBalam in this case, the factory responsible for creating new windows is a class that detects when more / new displays are turned on, which can happen any time when the application is running (same applies to unregistration; the app stays active in the background / system tray). and when the user clicks on the tray icon for instance then all the registered windows should be shown. so the question remains about conglomerating Window objects like this, and not Pages or any other ui elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do it, which is by making all my windows subclass `BaseWindow`, for both normal single `Window` objects and for `Window` objects actually containing multiple windows.

- Now when you call `.Show()` it will either show one window or multiple, depending on what is encapsulated in the subclass.

#### All Window objects should inherit from BaseWindow

```
public class BaseWindow : Window
{
    
    // Hide default implementation and call BaseShow instead
    public new void Show()
    {
        BaseShow();
    }

    protected virtual void BaseShow()
    {
        base.Show();
    }

    // ... abstract away any additional Window methods and properties required 
}
```

#### Override BaseShow()

```
public class MultiWindow : BaseWindow
{        
    private readonly IList<Window> _windows = new List<Window>();

    public void Register(Window window)
    {
        _windows.Add(window);
    }

    protected override void BaseShow()
    {
        foreach (var w in _windows)
           w.Show();
    }       
}
```

#### Set up MultiWindow in application startup

```
 // First Window object instantiated becomes WPF MainWindow     
 var multiWindow = new MultiWindow();
 multiWindow.Register(new WindowA());
 multiWindow.Register(new WindowB());
```

#### Use MultiWindow, but call overriden members through BaseWindow

```
// Cast down to BaseWindow in order to call the overriden member
var baseWindow = (BaseWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
// Show WindowA and WindowB
baseWindow.Show();
```

*P.S. I wish Microsoft employed interfaces throughout .NET, working with IWindow interface rather than the concrete Window class would provide much more power and in this case, also ease-of-implementation.*

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the startupuri will allow you to open a windows when the application start up
If you want to open windows when the application start up, you can do this way.

There is App.xaml file, please go to App.xaml.cs file.

please try...following

1. Remove StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml" in your App.xaml file.
2. App class inherited from Application. You can override OnStartup() to customize application stating up time.

   ```
       public partial class App : Application
       {
         private readonly IList<Window> _windows = new List<Window>();

         protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
         {
           base.OnStartup(e);        

           // Add windows you want to open here.
           foreach (var w in _windows)
           {
             w.Show();
           }
       }
   ```

I am not sure that this is what you want. I hope this help.

Comment: thanks for the code, but this is not what i want i.e. "I need a collection of windows that stick together and which I can easily call upon anywhere in my codebase, knowing I have one class that has taken care of the linkage"